# Configure pool connection jndi for Activemq in jboss 7

Tags: java, apache-axis, activemq-classic, connection-pooling, jboss7.x

I am using ActiveMq 5.4.3 and I am using a queue. I have my producer as a webservice(not a Ejb) and I had deployed the webserice war in jboss server. My service works fine. But every time when the service is called the connection and sessions are created and closed. I would like to overcome this bottleneck so that my connection and sessions are created only once when I start the server. How can I do this. I don't want jboss to act as a mdb container. I had deployed the activemq-rar inside my deploy folder of jboss and added the below subsystem to my standalone.xml

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:resource-adapters:1.0">
        <resource-adapters>
            <resource-adapter>
                <archive>
                    activemq-ra.rar
                </archive>
                <transaction-support>XATransaction</transaction-support>
                <connection-definitions>
                    <connection-definition class-name="org.apache.activemq.ra.ActiveMQManagedConnectionFactory" jndi-name="java:jboss/activemq/QueueConnectionFactory" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" pool-name="QueueConnectionFactory" use-ccm="true">
                        <config-property name="prefill">
                            false
                        </config-property>
                        <config-property name="max-pool-size">
                            20
                        </config-property>
                        <config-property name="ServerUrl">
                            tcp://localhost
                        </config-property>
                        <config-property name="use-strict-min">
                            false
                        </config-property>
                        <config-property name="min-pool-size">
                            5
                        </config-property>
                    </connection-definition>
                </connection-definitions>
                <admin-objects>
                    <admin-object class-name="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue" jndi-name="activemq/queue/outbound" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" pool-name="outbound">
                        <config-property name="Type">
                            javax.jms.Queue
                        </config-property>
                        <config-property name="Properties">
                            PhysicalName=queue.outbound
                        </config-property>
                    </admin-object>
                    <admin-object class-name="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQTopic" jndi-name="activemq/topic/inbound" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" pool-name="inbound">
                        <config-property name="Type">
                            javax.jms.Topic
                        </config-property>
                        <config-property name="Properties">
                            PhysicalName=topic.inbound
                        </config-property>
                    </admin-object>
                </admin-objects>
            </resource-adapter>
        </resource-adapters>
    </subsystem>
```

Now when I try to get the connection (code below) using the JNDI 
`PooledConnectionFactory connectionFactory = (PooledConnectionFactory) context.lookupLink("java:jboss/activemq/QueueConnectionFactory");`

I am getting the error as

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: org.apache.activemq.ra.ActiveMQManagedConnectionFactory -- service jboss.naming.context.java."org.apache.activemq.ra.ActiveMQManagedConnectionFactory
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy, use the PooledConnectionFactory.

You can do it by code and probably also by any XML config you have at hand:

```
ConnectionFactory cf = new PooledConnectionFactory(new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://localhost:61616"));
```

[Here](http://activemq.apache.org/spring-support.html) is a XML example usage (for spring, but you might get the idea from it)

Then it's just like any other connection factory.

```
Connection conn = cf.createConnection();
Session sess = conn.createSession..
```

[ActiveMQ aspects on chaching (mostly spring related)](http://activemq.apache.org/jmstemplate-gotchas.html)

Comment: Thx for ur suggestion. I had already tried PooledConnectionFactory but even then every producer is establishing the connection. I had done a bit to achieve this using JNDI but stuck with a error. So I had edited the question and posted the error.